# Attempting to calculate total in input type number form output

Tags: javascript, html, forms, output

I'm attempting to calculate the total based on the input in this input type number form (it's the first time I've ever done this) but I can't get it to output the amount based on the selection & I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. (i.e. if the item is $1.00 & they select "5", it'll output $5.00).
Here's my code:

```
 <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="amount.value = (quantity.valueAsNumber * (1)">
<legend>$1.00</legend>
<p><label for="quantity">QTY</label>
  <span>$</span><input type="number" min="1" max="5" id="quantity" name="quantity"></p>
 <p>Total: <strong>$<output name="amount" for="quantity"></output></strong></p>
</form>
```

Here's a link to my Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Tamara6666/fzgsbvpf/

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="">
<legend set="1">$1.00</legend>
<p><label for="quantity">QTY</label>
  <span>$</span><input type="number" min="1" max="5" id="quantity" name="rate"></p>
 <p>Total: <strong>$<output name="amount" for="quantity"></output></strong></p>
</form>
```

js

```
var dw = document.getElementById('quantity');
dw.onchange = function(){
var cur = this.value,
tocur = document.getElementsByTagName('legend')[0].getAttribute('set'),output = document.getElementsByTagName('output')[0];
var res = Math.floor(tocur * cur);
output.innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: can I ask u a quick ? @Glenn Wilkins? I'm trying to use this same form for 2 other values that have a float (they start at $2.50 & $.30) but when I"ve tried applying this same form,it's not working correctly for me w/the float values- do I need to take out the Math.floor or do something else differently?

Comment: <legend set="2.5">$2.50</legend>
          <form onsubmit="return false" oninput="">
<span class="quant"><p><label for="quant">QTY</label>
  <input type="number" min="1" max="5" id="quantity" name="rate"></p></span>
 <p>Total: <strong>$<output name="amount" for="quantity" id="total"></output></strong></p>
</form>                                                    [so var res = tocur * cur] ? @Glenn Wilkins?

Comment: or add another JS function to connect w/the different values? : var dw = document.getElementById('quantity2');
dw.onchange = function(){
var cur = this.value,
tocur = document.getElementsByTagName('legend2')[0].getAttribute('set'),output = document.getElementsByTagName('output')[0];
var res = (tocur * cur);
output.innerHTML = res;
}                                           @Glenn Wilkins ?

Answer (score 0):

With your exact code, all you are missing is a ')'.

**EDIT**

---

```html
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="amount.value = (quantity.valueAsNumber * (1))">
<legend>$1.00</legend>
<p><label for="quantity">QTY</label>
  <span>$</span><input type="number" min="1" max="5" id="quantity" name="quantity"></p>
 <p>Total: <strong>$<output name="amount" for="quantity"></output></strong></p>
</form>
```

**NOTE:** Just take into consideration that the output tag might not be supported in some browsers.

---

Here is a HTML5 + Jquery possible solution

```js
(function($){
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[name="rate"]').on('change keyup',function(){
     calculate(this, 'output[name="amount"]');
    });
  });
  
  function calculate(input, target){
   var value = $(input).val();
    $(target).val(value * 1); 
  }

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return false">
<legend>$1.00</legend>
<p><label for="quantity">QTY</label>
  <span>$</span><input type="number" min="1" max="5" id="quantity" name="rate"></p>
 <p>Total: <strong>$<output name="amount" for="quantity"></output></strong></p>
</form>
```